# How to write program to generate the following pattern?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

You can use recursion, loops, vectors or strings doesn't matter.

Given an input N will generate N lines of the pattern.

```
1
2
1 2
3
1 3
1 2 3
2 3
4
1 4
1 2 4
1 3 4
1 2 3 4
2 4
2 3 4
3 4
5
```

Edit: I figured out how to do it doing a pre-calculation. It is possible to do it iteratively one step at  a time?

```
void per(vector<int> v, int value) {

    cout << v;
    if (v.size() == value) {
        return;
    }

    if(v.back() < value && v.size() < value) {
        vector<int> modified(v);
        for(int i = 0; i < modified.size(); i++) {
            modified[i] += 1;
        }
        per(modified, value);
    }

    if(v.back() < value && v.size() < value) {
        // for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        vector<int> modified(v);
        modified.push_back(modified.back() + 1);
        per(modified, value);
    }


}
```

How do you think about such a recursive algorithm. I tried to draw a tree of the output but get suck. Maybe such problem doesn't fit well with recursion. It seems like it should be recursive and there is a smallest subset of the problem contained within.

Comment: Which part of the task is unclear to you? Have you started already? What have you tried?

Comment: @Zabuzard it isn't unclear to me I just don't know how to do it. do you? is it easy for you? show me your thought process in such a problem for bonus.

Comment: Show us YOUR thought process and related effort.  Then we know specifically where you're stuck and can help you out.  But you're pretty much asking us to write your entire code for you.  That's not what SO is.

Comment: It's a very strange pattern, you add the next number to all previous lines after doing a stable sort on the first number of each line. Because only the first number matters for the order you don't really have to sort if you maintain lists for each starting number and add new lines starting with that number at the end. So generating the lines for a new number is just adding the number itself then iterating those lists in order and adding the new number at the end while adding to the lists for the lookup.

Comment: @lfmunoz, What is your use cases for you expected specified result? The pattern is so confusing, Does specific order matter to you?

Comment: btw you could also get all previous lines starting with x with some clever calculations. Each number has 2^(number - 1) lines. The lines starting with x is always doubled for each new starting number.

Comment: @Nur do you have a solution for when order doesn't matter?  It is used as the foundation of an exhaustive search of a more complicated problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an iterative solution that involves, at iteration `i`, going through the previously added patterns that start with `j`, where j goes from 1 to `i-1`, and adding `i`.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static List<String> pattern(int n)
{
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        res.add(String.valueOf(i));
        
        for(int j=1; j<i; j++)
        {
            int size = res.size();
            for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
                if(res.get(k).equals(String.valueOf(j)) || 
                        res.get(k).startsWith(String.valueOf(j) + " "))
                {
                    res.add(res.get(k) + " " + i);
                }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Test:

```
for(String s : pattern(5)) System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
1
2
1 2
3
1 3
1 2 3
2 3
4
1 4
1 2 4
1 3 4
1 2 3 4
2 4
2 3 4
3 4
```

There may be a cleverer approach involving recursion that avoids having to iterate through the previously added patterns and checking the first character, but I'm yet to see it.

**EDIT**:

Note the original version above had a problem once numbers start getting into multiple digits - e.g. `startsWith(1)` starts matching `10`. I've updated the code to resolve this.

After playing around for a while I did manage to come up with a solution that I find more satisfying, which uses a combination of iteration and recursion to generate the list of entries at each given level. But it's not exactly simple.

```
static List<String> pattern(int n)
{
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        res.add(String.valueOf(i));
        
        for(int j=1; j<i; j++)              
            for(String s : list(i-1, j)) 
                res.add(String.format("%s %d", s, i));
    }
    
    return res;
}

static List<String> list(int i, int j)
{
    if(i == j) 
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(j)));
                    
    List<String> a = list(i-1, j);      
    for(int k=0, s=a.size(); k<s; k++) 
        a.add(String.format("%s %d", a.get(k), i));
    return a;
}
```

And a Javascript version.

```js
function list(i, j) {
    if(i === j) return [j];
  
  let a = list(i-1, j);
  a.forEach(s => a.push(s + ' ' + i));
  return a;
}

function gen(n) {
    let res = []
  
  for(let i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    res.push(i.toString());
    for(let j=1; j<i; j++) {
      list(i-1, j).forEach(s => res.push(s + ' ' + i));
    }
  }
    
  return res
}

gen(4).forEach(_ => console.log(_));
```

Comment: Thanks, can you say little bit of how you came up with that? Not really sure what to study to easily come up with these loops.

Comment: Honestly I just noticed the pattern, that each level just added the current value to the end of the previous values, but considered by level, rather than generated order. I still suspect there's a more elegant recursive solution - I'll update the answer if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to recursion for that,

Lets say we have an input `n: 3`, We need to create an array of `1..n` = `1,2,3`;

Where output should be:

```
1
2   12
3   13   23   123
```

```js
function createPowerSet(n) {
    let res = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        res.push([i])
        let len = res.length - 1;
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++)
            res.push(res[j].concat(i))
    }
    return res
}
console.log(createPowerSet(4))
```